# EGORefreshTableHeaderView checking connection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I use EGORefreshTableHeaderView to update my tableview.

Here I call my method to download the database:

```
- (void)reloadTableViewDataSource 
{ 
    [self downloadNewsDatabase];
    _reloading = YES; 
}
```

In this method (downloadNewsDatabase) I check internet connection. If the device is connected, I download my xml, I saved datas, ecc. Then I call this method

```
[self performSelector:@selector(doneLoadingTableViewData)];
```

And this works!

The problem is if the device is not connected. In fact, in that case I call immediately the doneLoadingTableViewData method but when I try to update one more time the tableview the EGOOPullRefreshLoading state is not set.

I think there is a problem with the contentOffset.y of the tableview (in egoRefreshScrollViewDidEndDragging the scrollView.contentOffSet is now 0.0 so the condition scrollView.contentOffset.y <= - 65.0f doesn't work anymore) but... what is wrong in my simple code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a delay on it, like:

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(doneLoadingTableViewData) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

Then it will work.